# increasing/lowering image opacity as a transition between lists of images

Tags: css, css-transitions, opacity

**What my code does:**

- creates a background
- changes background image with the next one in the list every 3 seconds
- loops back to the first image in the list at index 0 and repeats.

**What I want to happen:**

- each time we switch from one image to the next there is a transition
- every 3 seconds a new image opacity gradually increases from 0 to 100%
- then gradually decrease its opacity to 0 before switching to the next image

---

```
<div id="background" class="text-center background">

    <script type = "text/javascript">
        var background = document.getElementById("background");
        var currentPos = 0;
        var images = ["/images/backgroundimg1.jpg", "/images/backgroundimg2.jpg", "/images/backgroundimg3.jpg", "/images/backgroundimg4"], i = 0;

        function changeimage()
        {
            if (++currentPos >= images.length)
                currentPos = 0;

            background.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + images[currentPos] + ")";
        }
        setInterval(changeimage, 3000);
    </script>
</div>

<style>
.background{
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 1000px;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For myself, I would do it like this:

```js
var background = document.getElementById("background");
var currentPos = 0;
var images = ["https://i.stack.imgur.com/MraLT.jpg", "https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxVNC.jpg", "https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9VLC.jpg", "https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYG0R.jpg"],
  i = 0;

function changeimage() {
  if (++currentPos >= images.length) currentPos = 0;

  background.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + images[currentPos] + ")";
}
setInterval(changeimage, 3000);
```

```css
.background { display: grid; place-items: center; font: bold 48px sans-serif; text-shadow: 0 0 4px #fff, 0 0 2px #fff;

  height: 1000px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  transition: 2s linear;
}
```

```html
<div id="background" class="text-center background">Only transition</div>
```

---

But, if a transparency phase is needed, then:

- you can use a 1×1px transparent PNG image in Base64:

```js
var background = document.getElementById("background");
var currentPos = 0;
var images = ["https://i.stack.imgur.com/MraLT.jpg", "https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxVNC.jpg", "https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9VLC.jpg", "https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYG0R.jpg"],
  i = 0;

function changeimage() {
  if (++currentPos >= images.length) currentPos = 0;

  background.style.backgroundImage = `url('${images[currentPos]}')`;
  setTimeout(function() {
    background.style.backgroundImage = `url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVR42mNkYAAAAAYAAjCB0C8AAAAASUVORK5CYII=)`;
  }, 2500);
}
setInterval(changeimage, 4000);
```

```css
.background { display: grid; place-items: center; font: bold 48px sans-serif; text-shadow: 0 0 4px #fff, 0 0 2px #fff;

  height: 1000px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #0000, #0000);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  transition: 1.4s linear;
}
```

```html
<div id="background" class="text-center background">With transparent image</div>
```

- you can insert a pseudo-element as an underlay and use CSS variables:

```js
var background = document.getElementById("background");
var currentPos = 0;
var images = ["https://i.stack.imgur.com/MraLT.jpg", "https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxVNC.jpg", "https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9VLC.jpg", "https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYG0R.jpg"],
  i = 0;

function changeimage() {
  if (++currentPos >= images.length) currentPos = 0;

  background.style.setProperty('--bg', `url('${images[currentPos]}')`);
  background.style.setProperty('--op', 1);
  setTimeout(function() {
    background.style.setProperty('--op', 0);
  }, 2500);
}
setInterval(changeimage, 4000);
```

```css
.background { display: grid; place-items: center; font: bold 48px sans-serif; text-shadow: 0 0 4px #fff, 0 0 2px #fff;
  
  --bg: linear-gradient(to left, #0000, #0000);
  --op: 0;
  position: relative;
  height: 1000px;
}

.background::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; bottom: 0;
  left: 0; right: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  background-image: var(--bg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  opacity: var(--op);
  transition: opacity 1.4s linear;
}
```

```html
<div id="background" class="text-center background">Using pseudo element and CSS variables</div>
```